# Getting rid of role="navigation" in the Home Page Pagination

Tags: php, functions, pagination

For the Pagination on the front page ort the Homepage I am using this one →

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size' => 2 ) ); ?>
```

[Codex Reference #1](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_pagination/)

[Codex Reference #2](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination)

In the actual Browser, it generated a div like this →

```
<nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
```

W3C Validation is throwing this error →

> Warning: The navigation role is unnecessary for element nav.
>
> From line 301, column 2; to line 301, column 54
>            `↩   <nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">↩      <h2`

**Question →**

Is there a method to get rid of this →

```
role="navigation"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`navigation` is the default value for `role` attribute in `nav` elements. So, if the browser/technology understands HTML5 and is fully standard compliant, then it is unnecessary, but what if not? I don't get the advantage of removing it; it just make sure that any technology reading the document knows what the element is used for.

Anyway, if you want to remove it, you can [filter the navigation markup template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/navigation_markup_template/):

```
add_filter( 'navigation_markup_template', 'cyb_navigation_template' );
function cyb_navigation_template( $template ) {
    $template = '
    <nav class="navigation %1$s">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
        <div class="nav-links">%3$s</div>
    </nav>';

    return $template;

}
```

Comment: Code had no effect on latest wp twentysixteen theme

Comment: is there really need to add the $template argument in the function ?

Comment: The only reason I see here to remove the role="navigation" is for W3C validation which has impact in your website pagerank. But I agree with you. Some older browsers may need this to recognize the element.